# How to resolve Vue 3 custom renderer error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, custom-renderer, vite

I'm trying to build a custom renderer using Vue 3 and Vite. The renderer is working in its [original repo](https://github.com/SaFrMo/vite-minimum-renderer) (clone that repo, `npm install`, and `npm run dev`), but failing when I publish that renderer and install on another project.

To recreate, either:

- [Clone, install, and run this repo](https://github.com/SaFrMo/vite-external-renderer), or
- Create a Vue 3 project, npm install `mvp-renderer`, and import `{ createApp }` from `mvp-renderer` instead of `vue`.

The working custom renderer adds the class `custom-renderer` to every DOM element; in the broken version, nothing renders to the DOM and I see the following error when the `mount` function is called:

```
[Vue warn]: resolveComponent can only be used in render() or setup().
```

Any thoughts on how to fix?

Comment: I spent to much time on this, without any luck... But I think the mvp-renderer uses some builtin code of Vue (like  ensureRenderer()) and probably there will be 2 Vue renderers active at the same time while in DEV mode. Maybe the Vite Vue plugin adds a Vue renderer. The problem with this setup is that the internal Vue variable 'currentRenderingInstance' is null somehow and this could probably mean the 'createApp' function is missing some critical functionality.

Comment: @FerryKranenburg Thanks for checking it out! That definitely gives me a bit more to go on - I ran into a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64231911/vue-3-resolvecomponent-can-only-be-used-in-render-or-setup) but wasn't sure where to start to find that duplicate instance. I'll dig more into it and see what I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ferry Kranenburg's suggestion, I was able to find the fix for this - it looks like the problem was Vite adding some extra functionality.

I added a new `build:renderer` command to [the renderer](https://github.com/SaFrMo/vite-minimum-renderer/blob/main/package.json#L8) and it's working correctly when I install from NPM now. That command just runs a regular Typescript compile rather than doing Vite's full build process.

To see it in action, you can [clone the implementation](https://github.com/SaFrMo/vite-external-renderer) from above, run `npm install mvp-renderer@latest`, and run `npm run dev` see the it working without any errors.

Looks like prototyping a renderer in Vite works fine, but if you want to bundle it for production, you'll need to compile the renderer on its own. Thanks again Ferry!